# Chaosreader + Xephyr replay X11

Tags: linux, x11, xephyr

How to replay Chaosreader X11.replay session?
I tried this:

```
Xephyr -br -ac -noreset :1
DISPLAY=:1 ./session_0001.X11.replay
```

But got

```
ERROR42: Can't connect to X11 daemon on 127.0.0.1:6001 at ./session_0001.X11.replay line 57.
```

Comment: Tell us what happened when you tried it.

Comment: ERROR42: Can't connect to X11 daemon on 127.0.0.1:6001 at ./session_0001.X11.replay line 57.

Comment: Improve the question by editing the question.